# Hot after raining

Tags: word-usage

What do you call a type of weather when, for example, it was raining an hour ago but now the sun shines and it's very hot, so it's wet and hot at the same time and people pray for some wind.So if you are a steak you're rather boiled than fried. Disgusting weather if you ask me.

In Ukrainian we call it "парко, парить, вар" - where "пар" means "steam"

I've googled "steamy" it mostly gives me some ero photos in shower, so wanna know the appropriate word for the weather.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, glad to see you fixed the misspellings. Would you mind explaining what "ero photos" is? I tried looking it up and found the acronym Education Review Office among others, but that doesn't fit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the OP is asking about hot sticky weather, when the air is stifling and it's generally uncomfortable to be outdoors.

> ### muggy
>
> 1. (of the weather) unpleasantly warm and humid
>
> *[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/muggy)*

The following synonyms are also common and could be used in place of "muggy":

> humid, close, sticky, steamy, oppressive, airless, stifling, suffocating, stuffy, clammy, damp, moist, soupy, heavy, fuggy, *like a turkish bath*, *like a sauna*

I found a quote which illustrates perfectly the meaning of *muggy*

- *It was still light outside and muggy, like she was walking inside a giant’s mouth.*  ([source](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/muggy))
  <sub>Ivy Aberdeen’s Letter to the World</sub>

Comment: I don't agree that that this is specifically after raining, I would say it's more likely before. Humid would be a better word in my opinion.

Comment: @Bee the answer is based on what the OP said *it was raining an hour ago but now the sun shines* The air can be muggy before or after a rainfall.

Comment: No I agree that both work, I just wanted to point out that it may be misleading and could be misinterpreted to always mean before by the OP.